Use groupby and aggregate functions to reshape dataframe
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
A      B     C     D            E      F
foo    s     HO    02/01/24     100    20.0
foo    s     HO    02/01/24     200    20.0
foo    b     HO    02/01/24     100    20.0
foo    b     HO    02/01/24     200    20.0

bar    s     HO    02/01/24     100    20.0
bar    s     HO    02/01/24     200    20.0
bar    b     HO    02/01/24     100    20.0
bar    b     HO    02/01/24     200    20.0

fizz    s     BRT    02/01/24     100    20.0
fizz    s     BRT    02/01/24     200    20.0
fizz    b     BRT    02/01/24     100    20.0
fizz    b     BRT    02/01/24     200    20.0

buzz    s     PW    02/01/24     100    20.0
buzz    s     PW    02/01/24     200    20.0
buzz    b     PW    02/01/24     100    20.0
buzz    b     PW    02/01/24     200    20.0

I need to group these columns by ABCD and get the sum of E for each group and the first F in each group. Then I seperate the dfs into groups. Something like this:
df_groups = df.groupby(['A','C','B','D'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'E': 'sum', 'F': 'first'})
df_list = [x for _, x in df_groups.groupby(['A', 'B'])]

however I get stuck when I need to reshape it. I need the resultant df to look like this:
            D       A    E    F
B    C      
b   HO   02/01/24  foo  300  20
         02/01/24  bar  300  20
    BRT  02/01/24  fizz 300  20

    PW   02/01/24  buzz 300  20

s   HO   02/01/24  foo  300  20
         02/01/24  bar  300  20
    BRT  02/01/24  fizz 300  20

    PW   02/01/24  buzz 300  20

Im assuming I can do this with a groupby and an agg but I'm unsure

Code for input data:
data = {
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'buzz', 'buzz', 'buzz', 'buzz'],
    'B': ['s', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b'],
    'C': ['HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'PW', 'PW', 'PW', 'PW'],
    'D': ['02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24'],
    'E': [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
    'F': [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


what are the indexes in your expected df? B and C ?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh yes I just updated it to reflect that

@iBeMeltin why not just df_groups = df_groups.set_index(["B", "C"]).sort_index(); print(df_groups[["D", "A", "E", "F"]]) ?

Please provide data we can copy-paste without having to manually edit. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples especially under "Don't include a MultiIndex". That also includes the desired output, so that we can check if our results match.

I think for the sake of example you can remove D since it's all the same value

df.groupby(['B','C','D','A']).agg({'E': 'sum', 'F': 'first'}).reset_index(['D', 'A'])

What do you mean by "resultant df"? The result of your code is a list of dfs. It's also not in that order, but maybe you just forgot sort=False in df_groups.groupby(['A', 'B']).

@wjandrea yeah that is the code I have right now. I do not want it in seperate dfs like I am doing. I want it to look like the resultant df instead

@iBeMeltin "I do not want it in seperate dfs like I am doing." - Then why are you showing it as a list of dfs? Like, how is that relevant to the question?

@wjandrea to show what I was doing previously so i can fix it...

@iBeMeltin But how is that step relevant to the question?

You can do it this way:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'fizz', 'buzz', 'buzz', 'buzz', 'buzz'],
    'B': ['s', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b', 's', 's', 'b', 'b'],
    'C': ['HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'HO', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'BRT', 'PW', 'PW', 'PW', 'PW'],
    'D': ['02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24', '02/01/24'],
    'E': [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
    'F': [20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'E': 'sum', 'F': 'first'})
df_grouped = df_grouped.set_index(['B', 'C']).sort_index()
df_grouped = df_grouped[['D', 'A', 'E', 'F']]
print(df_grouped)

which gives
              D     A    E     F
B C                             
b BRT  02/01/24  fizz  300  20.0
  HO   02/01/24   foo  300  20.0
  HO   02/01/24   bar  300  20.0
  PW   02/01/24  buzz  300  20.0
s BRT  02/01/24  fizz  300  20.0
  HO   02/01/24   foo  300  20.0
  HO   02/01/24   bar  300  20.0
  PW   02/01/24  buzz  300  20.0

